# if-else on Latex file

Tags: if-statement, latex, pdflatex

I am new on Latex files. I searched about it a lot but couldn't find the proper answer. I have a file and the data is coming from a routine. I am sure that I have data here successfully. What I want to, in this table if 'F_1' is equal to text 'Tot.' I want to make the whole row bold else to keep it as below. I don't know if it's possible? Currently it's working as below without making bold.

```
     \rowStyleCond{%X_1%}{\itshape\rowfont{\small}}
        {%A_1%} &
        {%B_1%} &
        {%C_1%} &
        {%D_1%} &
        {%E_1%} &
        {%F_1%} \\
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: What are you using the replace the markers `%XXX%` with actual content?

Comment: They are cobol variables coming from a routine that calls this .tex file, they are coming that way, there is no other process to replace the markers. The problem is to write something like that:

if(%F_1% eq 'Tot.')
        {%A_1%} &
        {%B_1%} &
        {%C_1%} &
        {%D_1%} &
        bold{%E_1%} &
        bold{%F_1%} \\
else
        {%A_1%} &
        {%B_1%} &
        {%C_1%} &
        {%D_1%} &
        {%E_1%} &
        {%F_1%} \\
end-if.

but couldn't find the proper syntax for this.

Comment: What about [this paste](https://pastebin.com/raw/aKpdUBBS)? It uses `\pdfstrcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: I will try and let you know thanks Werner!